# HTTP/2 Request with Net Core 3 and HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, http2, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to make a HTTP/2 request in C#/NetCore with the following code:

```
public static class WebClient
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2Support", true);
        HttpResponseMessage response = Client.GetAsync("https://http2.pro/api/v1").Result;
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Version);
    }

    private static readonly CookieContainer CookieContainer =
        new CookieContainer();

    private static readonly HttpClientHandler HttpClientHandler =
        new HttpClientHandler
        {
            CookieContainer = CookieContainer,
            MaxConnectionsPerServer = 5,
        };

    public static readonly HttpClient Client = new HttpClient(HttpClientHandler)
    {
        Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan,
        DefaultRequestVersion = new Version(2, 0)
    };
}
```

However the servers always respond with HTTP 1.1. Does anyone know what is the problem? I'm using Net Core 3.1.101 on Windows 7 if that's important.

Comment: Must be a Windows 7 thing. It shows http2 when I run it in Win10. Maybe there's a registry tweak you can do or maybe it just is not supported.